# Show $Z_{n} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence, central-limit-theorem

Let $(X_{k})_{k \in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of independent random variables and $F_{k}=F_{X_{k}}$ the respective cdf functions of  $(X_{k})_{k \in \mathbb N}$ that are both continuous and strictly increasing.

Show that for $Z_{n}:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1+\log{(1-F_{k}(X_{k})))}$

$Z_{n} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

My ideas: 
I've realized there are two ways to show convergence in distribution, namely

through the

$i)$ Central Limit Theorem

$ii)$ or the very definition of the Cumulative distribution function

I suspect in this case, given the definition of $Z_{n}$, the CLT will be useful

It is clear since $(F_{k})_{k \in \mathbb N}$ are continuous that $(F_{k}(X_{k}))_{k \in \mathbb N}$ are independent random variables

The only problem is I see no way to get $(1+\log{(1-F_{k}(X_{k})))}$ into the form $\frac{F_{k}(X_{k})-\mathbb E [F_{k}(X_{k})]}{\sigma}$ that is necessary for the CLT.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: first show that $F_k(X_k)$ has the uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$. Then use this to calculate the mean and variance of $1+\log(1-F_k(X_k))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Let $U_k=F_k(X_k)$. Verify that $U_k$ 's are i.i.d with uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. Apply standard form of CLT.

Comment: Surely $U_{k}=F_{k}(X_{k})=P(X_{k}\leq X_{k})=1$ So, in order to find the distribution we look at the cdf of $U_{k}$, namely $F_{F_{k}(X_{k})}(c)=P(F_{k}(X_{k})\leq c)=P(1 < c)$, how can I glean the distribution of $U_{k}$ from this?

Comment: $P\{F_k(X_k) \leq t\}=P\{ X_k \leq F_k^{-1}(t)\}= F_k(F_k^{-1}(t))=t$ for all $t \in (0,1)$

Comment: Why is it necessary that $F_{k}$ is strictly increasing and continuous?

Comment: Is it so that $F_{k}^{-1}(t)$ exists?

Comment: @SABOY Yes, that is the reason.